# How can I limit my textbox text length takes 9 digits only using regex

Tags: c#, winforms

- string pattern = @"^[0-9]{0,9}$";
- return Regex.IsMatch(input,regFormat);
- I am using above pattern on keydown event Please help me how can I validate my textbox.textlength to max 9 digits using regex and takes only digits not string.

Comment: You can also use a masked textbox for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without regex I found my way out from this problem. below codes work awesome on my keydown event

```
else if (!(e.KeyValue >= 48 && e.KeyValue <= 57) || textBox1.Text.Length == 9)
{
   e.SuppressKeyPress = !(e.KeyCode == Keys.Back || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your regex to be limited to 9 characters, you can use curly braces, i.e.

```
/^[0-9]{0,9}$/
```

Comment: I take input from textbox only digits and want user enter only 9 digits. kindly share with me whole code on keydown event thanks scott

Answer (score 1):

To make a `TextBox` take only 9 characters, you can specify it's `MaxLength` attribute:

```
myTextBox.MaxLength = 9;
```

Then, if you only want the user to be able to enter numbers, handle the `TextChanged` event:

```
myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch("[^0-9]",myTextBox.Text)
        myTextBox.Text.Remove(myTextBox.Length - 1);
}
```

This checks if the last character of the `TextBox` is not a number, and if it is not a number, removes it.